# How can I replace "everything" with an idiom?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrase-request, phrases

I forgot an idiom that means "everything". "Lock, stock, and barrel", "the whole gamut", it's not that. Could you remind me of it? I think it contains "and".

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean:

> Kit and kaboodle

> kit and boodle. informal (often prec. by whole) the whole lot of persons or things; all of something. We took along the whole kit and caboodle in the station wagon. [Source](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/kit-and-caboodle)

Comment: Kit and kaboodle was the first thing to come to mind.  Also consider: *the whole shebang* and *the lot of it*.

Comment: And (in AmerE) *the whole nine yards*.

Comment: @nschneid I think it's what I struggled to recall. Thanks!